# Remove a line from a txt.file

Tags: java

Im trying to remove the first line of a txt file. I've been searching and i found out that we need to rewrite everything without taht line. I've seen every website nothing works help.

Comment: *rewrite everything without taht line* this should work, have you tired it?

Comment: Yes that's it: you need to rewrite the whole file... Didn't it work?

Comment: have a look at http://sscce.org/ ! Please give an example of what you tried so far, and what is making you block or where you're having a problem.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Java, but with the underlying file system.

Answer (score 1):

Java might not be the best tool for the job, try e.g.

```
tail -n +2 input.txt > output.txt
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid overwriting the entire file to remove the first line, this is how file works.

An alternative is to leave some space in front of each line and mark it when it is deleted, then periodically "overwrite" the file without marked lines.